# JPA Criteria 2 embebbed JOINs and condition between them

Tags: sql, criteria-api

I'm gonna adapt my problem to a simple example. Lets say I have 2 entities: Employee and EmployeeCompany (the class that defines the relation of a Employee with a Company).

I need to retrieve the Employee entities that are associated with 2 EmployeeCompany entities, and these 2 EmployeeCompany entities must share the same value for a specific attribute (let's call this attribute "X"). EmployeeCompany entities have also embebbed identifiers, so the entities definition would look something like this:

```
Employee:
    Long idEmployee;
    List<EmployeeCompany> employeeCompanies;

EmployeeCompany:
    // Embebbed ID
    EmployeeCompanyId id;
    Long X;

EmployeeCompanyId:
    Long idEmployee;
    Long idCompany;
```

This is what I'm currently doing to make the 2 JOINs with the EmployeeCompany tables starting from the Employee entity:

```
Root<T> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Join<Object, Object> joinFirstEmployeeCompanyId = root.join("employeeCompanies").join("id");
Predicate finalPredicate = builder.equal(joinFirstEmployeeCompanyId.get("idCompany"), idCompany1);
Join<Object, Object> joinSecondEmployeeCompanyId = root.join("employeeCompanies").join("id");
finalPredicate = builder.and(finalPredicate, builder.equal(joinSecondEmployeeCompanyId.get("idCompany"), idCompany2));
```

My problem is, I don't know how I can specify now that between these 2 joins, they must meet the X attribute condition (both EmployeeCompany entities must have the same value for the X attribute).

In case it helps, this is what the SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeCompany ec1 ON ec1.idemployee = e.idemployee AND ec1.idcompany = :idCompany1
INNER JOIN EmployeeCompany ec2 ON ec2.idemployee = e.idemployee AND ec2.idcompany = :idCompany2
WHERE c1.X = c2.X
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue this way:

```
Root<T> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Join<Object, Object> joinFirstEmployeeCompany = root.join("employeeCompanies");    
joinFirstEmployeeCompany.on(builder.equal(joinFirstEmployeeCompany.get("id").get("idCompany"), idCompany1));
Join<Object, Object> joinSecondEmployeeCompany = root.join("employeeCompanies");
joinSecondEmployeeCompany.on(builder.equal(joinSecondEmployeeCompany.get("id").get("idCompany"), idCompany2));
Predicate finalPredicate = builder.equal(joinFirstEmployeeCompany.get("X"), joinSecondEmployeeCompany.get("X"));
```